# Inconsistent invocation of Python versions with pythontex

Tags: pdftex, python

I'm getting what looks to me like anomalous behavior with the pythontex system. A minimal working example is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[gobble=auto]{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
  import sys
  this_python_version = sys.version.split()[0]
\end{pycode}

Python version according to pyconsole:

\begin{pyconsole}
import sys
sys.version.split()[0]
\end{pyconsole}

Python version according to py is \py{this_python_version}.

\end{document}
```

I run `pdflatex` and `pythontex --interpreter python:python3` to generate output that looks like:

[image]

The version reported via calculation using `\pyconsole` is 2.7.5, but the version calculated using `\py` is 3.4.2 (as I'd intended). For some reason, the `\pyconsole` invocation is not following the `--interpreter` command line specification and is invoking python rather than python3.

I'm using `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)` and `PythonTeX v0.12`. The installed pythons are

```
% python --version
Python 2.7.5
% python3 --version
Python 3.4.2
```

Any leads greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Mac OS X version 10.9.5. Sorry for the oversight.

Comment: Thought it might be OS X... (I've been there - not in relation to TeX but just trying to get it to use an updated version of `python`...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--interpreter` option doesn't work for console content.  Console content will use the default Python installation instead. There's already an issue open for this [here](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/24).

The current workaround is to run `pythontex2.py` or `pythontex3.py`, instead of `pythontex.py`, when you need to select a specific version for the console. I hope to have a fix for this relatively soon.

Comment: I'm using `latexmk` like this: `latexmk -pdf --shell-escape file_with_console_content.tex` and I cannot see how to use that suggested workaround, at all. How can I say `latexmk` to run `pythontex3.py` instead of `pythontex.py`? Maybe the answer is simple, but I'm stuck.

Comment: @colidyre You will have to modify how `latexmk` invokes PythonTeX to add `--interpreter`. Maybe edit the `.latexmkrc` and check the `latexmk` documentation as necessary.

Comment: Thx, I didn't manage to get it running with latexmk so far, but this seems to work: `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex && pythontex3 file.tex && pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex`.